# HAProxy timeout after 120 seconds

Tags: haproxy

I made a load balancer using HAProxy. My connections can takes up to 1-4 minutes, so I increased the default timeout values in HAProxy to 300s as follows:

```
global
    daemon
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    maxconn 2000

defaults
    log     global
    mode    tcp
    option  tcplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect 300s
    timeout client  300s
    timeout server  300s
    option http-keep-alive

frontend LOAD_BALANCER_TIER
    bind *:80
    default_backend WEB_SERVER_TIER

backend WEB_SERVER_TIER
    balance leastconn
    mode tcp
    server segmentingApi01 some_private_ip:7331 check tcp-ut 300000
    server segmentingApi02 some_private_ip:7331 check tcp-ut 300000
    server segmentingApi03 some_private_ip:7331 check tcp-ut 300000
```

As you can see I even increased the TCP connection in `server` options. Yet, my request to the load balancer timeout after exactly 120s. Please note that I believe the issue is from the load balancer as when I send a request to the servers directly (`some_private_ip:7331`) it does not timeout.

I was wondering if somebody could help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't think "redispatch" and "http-keep-alive" work in tcp mode - as haproxy does not deal with application (http) information in tcp mode.

Maybe you should give "option tcpka" a try. This does TCP keep alive, so the OS won't cancel the connection when no data is exchanged - which I guess is happening here.

You should not set connection timeout to such a high value, because this timeout is for making the initial connection to the server.